# AsyncTask return value late

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-asynctask, google-cloud-datastore

I have an authentication interface with an email field and a button.
When i click the button an AsyncTask should verify if the email exist in a google app engine datastore or not.
This is the code for my asyncTask:

```
public class ConnexionAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Inscrit> {
private static InscritApi inscritApi = null;
private Context context;
String email;
ProgressDialog dialog;


public ConnexionAsyncTask(Context context, String email) {
    this.context = context;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog.setMessage("Connexion en cours");
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Inscrit doInBackground(Object... params) {
    if (inscritApi == null) {
        InscritApi.Builder builder = new InscritApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                .setRootUrl( // some url );
        inscritApi = builder.build();
    }
    try {
        return inscritApi.get(email).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Inscrit inscrit) {
    MainActivity main = (MainActivity) context;
    main.setInscrit(inscrit);
    dialog.dismiss();
}}
```

And this is the MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Inscrit inscrit;
Button btncnx;
EditText emailcnx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btncnx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncnx);
    emailcnx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailcnx);
    btncnx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ConnexionAsyncTask task = new ConnexionAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, emailcnx.getText().toString());
            task.execute();
            if (inscrit == null)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
public void setInscrit(Inscrit inscrit) {
    this.inscrit = inscrit;
}}
```

So the code should work like this:

1. the MainActivity should give the "inscrit" variable to the ConnexionAsyncTask
2. the ConnexionAsyncTask should verify if the email exist in the datastore or not and then put the result (Inscrit instance or null) in the "inscrit" variable with a setter
3. the MainActivity should verify if "inscrit" is null or not and show a toast

When i run my code i have to click 2 times to get the real result for example if i put "user@gmail.com" and this email exist of course in the datastore it will show me "not exist" for the first time and exist for second that's mean that the AsyncTask return the value just after the verification.
If i return value with .execute().get() it works but it blocks the ui thread and i want to show a progress Dialog.
I've tried to use a callback interface but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the checking

```
if (inscrit == null)
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

after your AsyncTask has finished executing. Basically, you are safe to check on inscrit nullability onPostExecute.

Comment: Thanks that really works i just have to add what i want it to execute after the **AsyncTask** in a method and call it from the **onPostExecute**